# How does emacs write files?

Tags: backup

When Emacs saves a file (`save-buffer`, `write-file` etc.), does it overwrite files directly or does it create a temporary file first?

More specifically, if I edit `/path-to/file.txt`, will Emacs directly open that file and overwrite the contents in-place, or will it write to a temporary file and replace the original file by it after successfully closing the file handle?

The latter convention is seen in a lot of other software. If Emacs has this behavior, or can be configured to use it, for my purposes it would be safe to disable backup files (`M-x customize-variable make-backup-files`).

Answer (score 2):

As an answer I cite here mostly the comments of the normal execution path in [`basic-save-buffer-2`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/261b060f12234baa6912ef40a9ce1a054f583ad0/lisp/files.el#L5331-L5429) which is the working horse of `save-buffer`:

```el
      ;; Write temp name, then rename it.
      ;; This requires write access to the containing dir,
      ;; which is why we don't try it if we don't have that access.
        ;; Create temp files with strict access rights.  It's easy to
        ;; loosen them later, whereas it's impossible to close the
        ;; time-window of loose permissions otherwise.
          ;; Call write-region in the appropriate way
          ;; for saving the buffer.
          (write-region nil nil tempname nil realname
                buffer-file-truename)
          ;; If we failed, restore the buffer's modtime.
        ;; Since we have created an entirely new file,
        ;; make sure it gets the right permission bits set.
        ;; We succeeded in writing the temp file,
        ;; so rename it.
        (rename-file tempname buffer-file-name t)
```

So in the normal case you are right that Emacs writes to a temp file and changes its name later to the value of `buffer-file-name` which is the name of the original file.

But, note that there are bypasses that circumvent the normal execution. See, e.g., the doc strings of the variables [`write-file-functions` and `write-contents-functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Buffers.html).